# Performance suffers when including lots of images in the app bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, compilation

I'm making an application that contains about 4000 images. This takes too long to compile and run because there are so many images in the bundle. Is there are any way to make this faster, like compiling a static or dynamic library, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

What's taking so long is actually installing an app that large on the device prior to running. The compilation time shouldn't be affected by how many resources you have in your app's bundle. There's really no way around it, unless you completely change your design and host the images on a remote server, which I'm guessing defeats the purpose.

Comment: Hi @Matt Thanks, the slow loading is before to launch the app when I make in xcode run to prove the app in my iphone this take so much time to load but when is loaded in my app is normal run faster but if I make some changes or something to prove again to make run in xcode this take so much time to run again, Is there are any way to have pre compiled all the images or something more to make xcode run faster?

Comment: @NTTake, Every time you make a change to the source in Xcode, the app needs to be recompiled, and reinstalled on the device. The compilation speed isn't the problem. The bottleneck is reinstalling the app, because it involves copying 4000 images from Xcode to your device. No matter what you do with static libraries, those images have to make it from Xcode to the device somehow. As noted, the only way to decrease your launch time when building and running would be to not bundle the images with the app, and instead load them from a remote server after launch.

Comment: It's also possible that just zipping up the app is taking a while -- the final app bundle is really just a .zip file with all of the files (executable, plist, images, other data files, etc.) in it, and zipping up a lot of data takes a while.  So the combined archiving + transfer to the device will be slower the more data you have.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to not build your images with the app. Just build your app without any media and then download all the media at first start with a splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider how you can accomplish your drawing programmatically in some cases.

You certainly don't want all those images in your binary (well, it wouldn't be a problem if they were a few pixels each).

You might consider a monolithic binary of your pngcrushed images which you read as data -- on demand, image by image just like you would image files. This would be implemented quite infrequently. Of course, that won't help the transfer times significantly, but it can reduce time spent pngcrushing and other resource processing steps.

Answer (score 0):

How and when  you load th images? I might be wrong, but I think the amount of files that are compiled into the bundle shouldn't affect the loading time hat much. Do you load them all at startup?